# woocommerce product category search filter showing other category products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any idea why this query is showing products inside a different parent category and it's children? http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=white&product_cat=floral

It should only show the product "White Floral Product Test"

White this query works properly: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=white&product_cat=rentals
Notice how the working string above doesn't show "White Floral Product Test"

Here is the search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for products" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_cat" value="floral" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The only variation in the form is `name="product_cat" value="rentals"`

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is that WordPress will search for the search term in the provided WooCommerce category and its child categories. To change that, you may have to use the `pre_get_posts` action to change the query itself not to include the child categories.

For example:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'woo_alter_category_search');
function woo_alter_category_search($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !is_search())
        return false;

    if ($product_cat = $query->get('product_cat')) {
        $query->set('product_cat', '');
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $product_cat,
                'include_children' => false,
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this code is not tested - it is just an example.

Comment: Hmm it's still showing the children of the other parent category, I added the action code into my functions file: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=white&product_cat=floral